# Calculating confidence factor in Viola–Jones face detection?

Tags: c++, opencv, face-detection, confidence-interval

I am trying to use Viola–Jones face detection algorithm in OpenCV. I use the `detectMultiScale()` to locate multiple faces in image. I am wondering how is it possible to return from the source code or to calculate a confidence factor for the face that are calculated. It seems that by default `detectMultiScale()` function doesn't return a conf factor.

Comment: i believe the minneighbours parameter is a measure of confidence you are looking for, it's not as fine grain as a continous variable though

Comment: Actually is not a elegant measurement. Is there a way to have access to adaboost weights and thresholds so as to calculate the output??

Comment: The returned faces, are the ones with the biggest factor?? How does the algorithm choose which faces are the one that it ll returned??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no confidence score to return but you can set how confident you want by setting `minNeighbors`. The higher, the better quality, also the less faces.

- **minNeighbors** – Parameter specifying how many neighbors each candidate rectangle should have to retain it ([documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/objdetect/doc/cascade_classification.html#cascadeclassifier-detectmultiscale)).

---

**Edit**: If you use Python, you can modify the quality by setting `rejectLevels`.

```
Python: cv2.CascadeClassifier.detectMultiScale(image, rejectLevels, 
    levelWeights[, scaleFactor[, minNeighbors[, flags[, minSize[, maxSize[,      
    outputRejectLevels]]]]]]) → objects
```